# android enable and disable view

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating an app to communicate via bluetooth. I want first to enable my entire view until the connection establishes. Then when I click a button, I want a text view to be enabled to send a string via bluetooth.
If I disable it in onCreate(), how can I enable it runtime?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_data);
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        terminal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.terminal);
        terminal.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Comment: Basically you can enable it in the same way you disabled it. Please post some code for more info.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.send_data);
     init();
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
 private void init() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  terminal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.terminal);
  terminal.setEnabled(false);
  
 }
I want to enable the terminal in runtime when the connection establishes

Comment: Edit your question with that code. Also add the code where you want the view to be set to enabled.

Comment: Consider about first defining a receiver who can detect and handle the connection status on your Bluetooth.

Comment: i did not understand clearly what you want to do but i want to give a quick fix for your problem. insert a transparent layout to bottom of your root layout and set it's width and height "match_parent", make it clickable. when you handle connection successfully remove it or remove its clickable or its click handler.

Comment: I want to enable the (EditText)terminal when a static boolean data from main activity set to to true at runtime.